# Moving the entire canvas

Tags: android

I'm making an Android game and I have shaped that I am drawing and they get big enough to leave the screen, I want to be able to move the canvas itself, so that I can center those shapes into the screen, and then go back to them being gone.

Is there such a way to move the canvas? i.e

```
canvas.move(10, 10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can translate the canvas, draw your game and than restore it. You can also draw part of it, translate and draw some more and than restore and continue drawing.
For example:

```
int offsetX = 10;
int offsetY = 10;
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(offsetX, offsetY);
    canvas.drawRect(box.x, box.y, box.x2, box.y2, paint);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

Other option is to define an x,y offset that represents the amount you want to move the canvas and for each draw add this offset to the drawing.
For example:

```
int offsetX = 10;
int offsetY = 10;
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawRect(offsetX + box.x, offsetY + box.y, offsetX + box.x2, offsetY + box.y2, paint);
}
```